# how to use images as radio buttons

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to create a simple enabled/disabled radio button grouping on a form. I had planned on using an image of a check mark for enabled and an x disabled. I want the element that wasn't clicked to go gray to make it clear which is selected. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que usted ha intentado ?

Comment: I don't mean to hijack your question, but I did a lot of usability studies on using images for check boxes and it was a complete disaster.  People only recognize *real* HTML checkboxes.  You can read about my experiences [here](http://blog.kitchenpc.com/2012/04/13/the-white-whale-of-usability/).

Comment: @MikeChristensen, interesting read and very informative. As always usability should come first.

Comment: @TheEliteNoob - Thanks.  When I fixed it, 9 out of 10 people got the check boxes.  I was completely amazed..

Comment: @MikeChristensen i think it depends on the user skills in web, because a person who's familiar working with web 2.0 apps can determinate easily the target of the controls, no that way some one with  afraid to web or pc apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
    $('input:radio').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('<a class="radio-fx" href="#"><div class="radio"></div></a>').insertAfter(this);
    });
    $('.radio-fx').live('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
          var $check = $(this).prev('input');
          $('.radio-fx div').attr('class','radio');
          $(this).find('div').attr('class','radio-checked');          
          $check.attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.radio {
    background: url(radiobutton_no.png) no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.radio-checked {
    background: url(radiobutton_yes.png) no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```